# Using Swagger-annotation to represent a complex property as a String

Tags: java, spring, rest, swagger

In a Java/Spring ReST application, I'm using swagger-annotations 1.3.7  I have a number of small classes (for example, GenderCode) that I use as properties in my ReST models. These classes have a single public property, called *value*. Using Jackson, my APIs can accept a simple String *s* and construct an instance of, say, GenderCode with its *value* set to *s*. Similarly, it can serialize a GenderCode as a simple String (which of course represents the value of *value*).

I would like my Swagger documentation to represent these objects as simple strings, since that represents what the JSON will look like. Instead it represents an complex type with a "value" key:

```
{
  "genderCode": {
    "value": ""
  },
  ...
}
```

It should look simply like this:

```
{
  "genderCode": "",
  ...
}
```

Here's what the Java model would look like:

```
public class Person {

    @JsonProperty("genderCode")
    @Valid
    @KnownEnumValue
    @ApiModelProperty(value = "GenderCode", dataType="string", required = false,
            allowableValues=GenderCode.POSSIBLE_VALUES_DISPLAY)
    private GenderCode genderCode;

    ...

}
```

Here's the definition of that property within the API definition file that Swagger generates:

```
"genderCode":{"enum":["ANY","M","F"],"description":"GenderCode","required":false,"type":"GenderCode"}
```

I've tried using an OverrideConverter, but that had no effect. Any thoughts on how this can be done?